# Почему не срабатывает событие onfullscreenchange при нажатии F11?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function FS(event){console.log("FULL SCREEN CHANGE")}, false);  
  document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function (event){console.log("FULL SCREEN CHANGE")}, false); 
  document.addEventListener("MSFullscreenChange", function (event){console.log("FULL SCREEN CHANGE")}, false); 
  document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function (event){console.log("FULL SCREEN CHANGE")}, false); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Такой код реагирует на **requestFullscreen** и **cancelFullScreen**, но если нажимать F11 консоль остается пустой.

Answer (score 0):

У <kbd>F11</kbd> `Event: keydown`, который надо ловить.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Do what ever you need here...
  if (e.keyCode === 122) // F11 pressed
    console.log(e.keyCode);
})
```

```css
.clk {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}

kbd {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: .2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="clk">
  <p>Кликнуть в квадрате для срабатывания скрипта, потом нажать <kbd>F11</kbd>.</p>
  <p>Кликнуть в квадрате для срабатывания скрипта, потом нажать <kbd>F11</kbd>.</p>
  <p>Кликнуть в квадрате для срабатывания скрипта, потом нажать <kbd>F11</kbd>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: это понятно, но в событии keydown, не знаю (браузера, document или body), разве нет кода типа "if (e.keyCode === 122) {вызвать функцию перевода в fullscreen}", в результате вызова которой происходит **event onfullscreenchange**. Так как это происходит когда я вызываю requestFullscreen()

Comment: проще говоря, почему при изменении полноэкранного режима с помощью  requestFullscreen() событие onfullscreenchange происходит, а с помощью F11 нет, ведь режим экрана меняется в обоих случаях